# Flutter & Firestore: Is it a good idea to add data within a transaction function?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

The code below is my member enrollment function.

I want to make sure the new document is successfully created in Firestore before increasing `memberCount`.

```dart
var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
await db.runTransaction((transaction) async {
  final memberCountDoc = db.collection('variables').doc('memberCount');
  final snapshot = await transaction.get(memberCountDoc); // get total num of members right now
  int newMemberCount = snapshot.get('value') + 1;
  Map<String, dynamic> userdata = {
    'sequence': newMemberCount, // specify the value
    'enrollTime': DateTime.now().toUtc(),
  };
  var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  db.collection('users').doc(user!.uid).set(userdata); // add a new doc to record userdata
  transaction.update(memberCountDoc, {'value': newMemberCount}); // finish transaction
  return newMemberCount;
}).then(
  (value) => print('Now you have $value members!'),
  onError: (e) => print(e),
);
```

Is it a good idea to add data within a transaction function?

I afraid there are bugs that I haven't noticed yet, or it's not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The coded looks fine at first glance to me.

One optimization was to use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) operation instead of a transaction, by using the [atomic increment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value) operator instead of a read-then-write operation. This will increase the scalability of the system, as the whole read-then-write now happens on the database server, rather than in your code.